# Error while using node module in SAP UI5 app

Tags: sapui5, node-modules, sap-fiori, sap-business-application-studio

The requirement is to use of the node modules in my controller file of a UI5 app. I've installed the module and it resides in my npm_module folder. Based on the below blog, I've added some configurations in my ui5.yaml, yet I get the error pasted below.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Blog Referred: https://blogs.sap.com/2020/07/30/project-shims-using-npm-modules-with-ui5/

Code screenshot
[image]

Error: **failed to load 'thirdparty/aws-sdk.js' from resources/thirdparty/aws-sdk.js: script load error**

Comment: Did you add aws-sdk to your ui5dependencies in the package.json?

Comment: yes, it is present in package.json as well.

   ` "ui5": {
        "dependencies": [
            "@sap/ux-ui5-tooling",
            "@sap/ui5-builder-webide-extension",
            "ui5-task-zipper",
            "mbt",
            "aws-sdk"
        ]
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1055.0",
        "ui5-tooling-modules": "^0.1.1"
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Update: The issue was the path mentioned in the controller. I changed it to refer to the dist folder where the actual aws-sdk.js existed. And it resolved the error.